# Haxe DOMStringMap values not accessible

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, haxe

I'm trying to access the 'data-*' attributes on an element in the browser in Haxe.

```
var element = document.getElementById('#someId');
var dataLabel = 'label'; //'data-label'
element.dataset[dataLabel] = 5;
```

That code (which works in plain javascript) generates two compilation errors in HaxeDevelop.

1. "String should be Int"
2. "For function argument 'data'"

How can I access element datasets in Haxe? Is there a known proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Element#getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [Element#setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) methods to accomplish the same functionality.

```
var element = document.getElementById('#someId')
var dataLabel = 'label'; //'data-label'
element.setAttribute('data-' + dataLabel, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a downside of how the array access operator works in Haxe.

Only `abstract` types can define array access, as [the manual states here](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html).

Haxe's [DOMStringMap](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/3.4.7/std/js/html/DOMStringMap.hx) is just an extern class, so it can't have array access that uses `String` as a key instead of `Int`.

Now, there are ways around this. The `untyped` keyword [seen here](https://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-injection.html) is one way your initial example could work. `untyped` isn't recommended though, it's a slippery slope to fragile code that you should avoid whenever possible.